# wrap text from sql query in php

Tags: php, sql, word-wrap

I have an sql query in php which returns sql data type text and the string thats returned roughly 200 characters is over flowing off the screen.

I want to wrap the text so it stays in a div using about 50% width. I have tried wordwrap function and putting the output in p tags but that is not working.

Any ideas.

Answer (score 2):

This CSS should fix it:

```
word-wrap: break-word;
```

It will break even long continual string if needed.

More details here: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/CSS/word-wrap

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
.yourclass { 
   white-space: pre-wrap;      /* CSS3 */   
   white-space: -moz-pre-wrap; /* Firefox */    
   white-space: -pre-wrap;     /* Opera <7 */   
   white-space: -o-pre-wrap;   /* Opera 7 */    
   word-wrap: break-word;      /* IE */
}
```